# In app script, how to include script.html file (without <script> tag) in index.html

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I have google app script application and the file script.html is included in index.html using the function below, and it works fine. However, script.html have script tag, which prevents searching through function difinitions, I want to include script.html in index.html without having script tag in script.html file.

The include function:

```
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}
```

Comment: You can search through all of the project files using Apps Script API

Comment: I  like to load all of the project files into a spreadsheet and the use ctrl-r to search

Answer (score 0):

Simply put the script tabs in the html page.

**HTML_Test**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="test" type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="testOnClick()">
    <script>
      <?!= include("JS_Test"); ?>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JS_Test**

```
function testOnClick() {
  alert("Hello");
}
```